# Yii2 GridView: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, yii2

could someone explain me why I'm getting this error? I've tried to search related information, but couldn't find what would be useful.

Here is my function:

```
$query = Recipient::find()->from('recipient')
            ->joinWith(['delivers'])
     
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,

    ]);
```

Error is:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in
> order clause is ambiguous

The SQL being executed was:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `recipient` 
LEFT JOIN `deliver` ON `recipient`.`id` = `deliver`.`recipient_id` 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: if `deliver` table has an `id` field, it doesn't know which one it has to choose. So you have to specify the table in the `ORDER BY` statement. `recipient.id` or `deliver.id`. Since you are using a Framework, either use the plain text sql features (if it exists) or change the structure of the table to no have duplicate name of field.

Comment: Yes. I correct relation function: public function getDelivers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Deliver::className(), ['recipient_id' => 'id'])->orderBy(['deliver.id' => SORT_DESC]);
    }

Comment: Remove it from your relation and add it to your query builder

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Recipient::find()->from('recipient')->joinWith(['delivers'])->orderBy(['`recipient`.`id`' => SORT_ASC]);
```

In above example, column name is explicitly specified to avoid *ambiguity* error.

Code seems incomplete.  Post more code, so we can help you.